# ValueError: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'RESIZE_BILINEAR' version '3' Registration failed

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, yolo, tensorflow-lite

I am using yolov4 tiny on raspberry pi4 with 2GB module.

I install the almost all packages and activate the environment.install tensor-flow and tft-lite but when i execute the detection.py code i get the error.

Value Error: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'RESIZE_BILINEAR' version '3' Registration failed.

i am using the code of  "theAIGuysCode" ...

repo link = https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-custom-functions

Comment: How you installed tensorflow and setup your environment in general?

Comment: pip3 install tensorflow

Comment: version of the tensorflow is 2.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is mismatch of converter version and runtime version. Make sure you use [recommended setup](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-custom-functions) (tf 2.3.0):

> ## Conda (Recommended)
>
> Tensorflow CPU conda env create -f conda-cpu.yml conda activate yolov4-cpu
>
> Tensorflow GPU conda env create -f conda-gpu.yml conda activate yolov4-gpu
>
> ## Pip
>
> TensorFlow CPU pip install -r requirements.txt
>
> TensorFlow GPU pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt

Check installed version (call print(tf.**version**) or check requirements.txt ) and install same version for your [RPi](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#raspberry-pi).

Comment: Thanks for your response. i try to update tf to 2.3.0rc0 but get error unable to satisfied your request

Comment: Is this problem on rpi or pc? Try to change to "2.3.0" it is released long time ago

Comment: this problem on RPi only

Comment: Did you try version 2.3.0? (not RC)

Comment: What is maximum version number you can get on RPi?

Comment: did u find any solution @muhammadjahanzaibKhan

Comment: i reinstall the Raspbian and again reinstall tensorflow 2.3.0 .